# Dynamically change page content between divs without affecting other elements

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, user-interface, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a single page where content will be loaded instead of redirecting a user to a new page  once a link is clicked . I've tried this using ajax but i'm still redirected to another page
Here is what i have done so far

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <p> welcome page</p>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html">home</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="about.html">About</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <p>Hello page</p>
        <div id="content">
            <p>Content is loaded here</p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("ul.nav li a").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var url = $(this).attr('href'); //get the link you want to load data from
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: url,
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("#content").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help please !

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues.

First, the jquery selector is not correct so you are not attaching the click listener to the right element, `nav li a`

Second, since you are using the href attribute that the browser will be following, you need to `return false` in your click listener to prevent such behavior

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("nav li a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); //get the link you want to load data from
    $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: url,
     success: function(data) {
        $("#content").html(data);
    }
   });
   return false;
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <p> welcome page</p>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">home</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">About</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>Hello page</p>

    <div id="content">
      <p>Content is loaded here</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing is returned now after clicking the link

Comment: There may be other issues, like CORS, dependent on your specific setup. You need to check the browser console. I have modified the above to return text from a cdn (which is straightforward accessible) in order to show that the original problem is solved. Click on "About" to test

Comment: Yeah you're correct its CORS. I've done some google search and i'm told the pages on my about and home link should be loaded directly from a web server and not my disk.I'm using apache web server its up and running but i  just cant  figure out how to load html file from a web server

Answer (score 0):

The **selector** you're using is not correct; `nav` is an element, not a class. So you can use any of the following:

```
ul li a OR
ul > li > a OR
nav ul li a OR
nav > ul > li > a OR
nav a
//etc
```

You also need to include **jQuery** - be sure the following appears before your JS:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Lastly your **HTML is malformed**; you do not have a closing tag for `div.header`:

```
</div>
```

which can be inserted just before the script tag(s).

The rest of your JS code is correct and should work once you correct the selector but I would suggest you consider using the `.load()` method for it's conciseness:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('nav ul li a').on('click', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load(url);
    });
});
```